# Symfony minimum package for console application

Tags: php, symfony

By default, to use symfony standard package, there are some packages that may not need to use by the command line such Template engine, security, asset

I would like to know a minimal set of composer package which allow me to make console application with ability to use YML configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Just require [symfony/console](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/console) and let composer handle the dependencies.  It's unclear what you mean by "application", since that can mean a lot of things.  But you can always add [HttpFoundation](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/http-foundation) or [DependencyInjection](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/dependency-injection) to start building it out.  But your question is literally what composer is there for :)

Comment: I think only symfony/console may not be able to read yml configuration. and I may also need to use a service in a kernel like the web to use in symfony standard..

Comment: If you include the DependencyInjection component, you'll have access to the container and so adding future dependencies becomes really easy.  An alternative approach would be to just use Symfony Standard Edition and remove dependencies you don't need as you go.